# curl get value from outside website need username and password

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get some value form outside website which need username and password.
normally I need go to login page first(https://xxx.xxx.xxx/HomeAccess), then go to https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.aspx. But if without login just go to the page xxx.aspx, I will get errror "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.";

in PHP I'm trying use this code

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.aspx';
$username ='uuuuu';
$password ='ppppp';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $output;

?>
```

I got blank page.

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how the authorization is set up on that site, but usually, when you log in, they give some kind of access token as a cookie and you use that access any of the other pages in the site. So use curl to hit the login page with the username and password, grab the cookie, then curl again to your desired page.

Again, that all depends on the site you're trying to access. You'd have to do some digging to find out where the login is taking place and how they authenticate/authorize.

Comment: thanks. that web site is asp.net with ssl. don't know how get the token. Can you give me some details?

Comment: I would inspect the request through Chrome's/Firefox's network inspector. The response will generally give you a token. Then when you access the desired page, the request will use that same token, generally. Please upvote :P

Answer (score 0):

Curl can give you a pretty good hint by doing this:

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ('.curl_error($ch).'): '.curl_error($ch);
}
```

My guess is that you've got an SSL Cert verification issue. But it really could be 20 different things. If you could include your $info values in your initial question that would also be helpful.

Comment: [url] => https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.aspx
 [content_type]=>[http_code]=>0 [header_size] =>0 [request_size] =>0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] =>0 [redirect_count] =>0 [total_time] => 0.047 [namelookup_time] =>0 [connect_time] =>0.047 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => ***.***.***.*** [local_port] => 16370 [redirect_url] =>

Comment: http_code as 0 is really odd. Are you sure that you're not getting blocked by a firewall on your local machine? To test, change your URL to something like http://www.google.com and make sure you get HTML back.

Assuming you are, try this:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

That'll turn off SSL cert and end-point validation. If that works, fire up google and look for how to add certs to your local PHP install.